# Woher kommt das Wort »Heia«?

Tags: etymology, baby-talk

Das Wort **[Heia](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=Heia)** für *Bett* haben meine Eltern in meiner Kindheit oft verwendet, wenn es für mich Zeit war schlafen zu gehen:

> Heia machen ( = schlafen gehen)
>   in die Heia gehen ( = ins Bett gehen )
>   Jetzt aber ab in die Heia!

Gelegentlich verwendet mein Vater es allerdings heute noch, und zwar auf sich bezogen:

> Ich geh' in die Heia.

Woher kommt das Wort?

Comment: Für einen Heiermann verrate ich's. :)

Comment: Danke, der Heiermann war ein guter [Hinweis](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Heiermann&suchspalte[]=rart_ou).

Comment: I found this but I'm not sure it answers your question completely: "Einmal wird auf ein bair. "heide", griech. "heude" = "schlafe" verwiesen, wonach "Heidschibumbeidschi" als "heude, mu paidion" = "schlafe, mein Kindlein!" zu erklären wäre.
Hierzu passt auch das im Saarland zu hörende kindersprachliche "Heia machen" = "schlafen". "

Comment: @Gigili This is indeed a possible answer to my question. It suggests that "Heia" comes from greek imperative "heude" = "sleep".

Comment: @hmundt: Oh I see, I thought you were interested in etymology of "Heia machen" which it says almost nothing about.

Comment: Vgl. "hängen", und "hangen" (cf. [Grimm/Woerterbuchnetz](www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GH02466#XGH02466) und Goth. *hahan*, prät. \* haihan. Erinnert nur wenig an *Heia*. Wird bei Wiktionary nicht geführt, dafür vergleichbare Formen schon im Ur-Germanischen. Semantisch liegt es nicht weniger fern. Die englische Glosse *suspend* weckt gewisse Assoziationen. Ein Vergleich zu *Hängematte* ist anfänglich scheinbar irreführend (phono-semantisches Calque aus Süd-Amerika) doch ist wohl nur das Wort geliehen. s. a. "sich hinhauen"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible origination is:

> Einmal wird auf ein **bair. "heide", griech. "heude"** = "schlafe" verwiesen, wonach "Heidschibumbeidschi" als "heude, mu paidion" = "schlafe, mein Kindlein!" zu erklären wäre. **Hierzu passt auch das im Saarland zu hörende kindersprachliche "Heia machen" = "schlafen".**

Another possible [origination](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Heiermann&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) is:

> *ein Heiermann* umgangssprachlich; überwiegend in Nord- und Westdeutschland; Soll aus dem Begriff "Heuer" der Hamburger Seeleute stammen, die 5 DM die Stunde - einen Heuermann - bekamen. Daraus wurde später der Heiermann (Hinweis eines Nutzers).
>   Nach Ansicht eines anderen Nutzers kommt der Begriff "Heiermann" tatsächlich aus Hamburg - aber nicht direkt von der Heuer der Seeleute, sondern indirekt vom Preis der Dienstleistungen, die sie sich damit erkauft haben: **In die Heia gehen. Oder anders ausgedrückt: Für eine "Dame" auf der Reeperbahn betrug der Preis damals für einmal zusammen "in die Heia gehen" 5 DM.** [..]

Comment: Very pleasing, but extremely unlikely, ΕΥΔΕΙΝ was rare even in ancient times (Source: Woodhouse) , but could have been known to Westerners either from the compound ΚΑΘΕΥΔΕΙΝ or as a (rare) platonic verb. But I doubt a Bavarian decided by himself to lull his Children to sleep with rare platonic verbs. Verbs like ΚΑΤΑΔΑΡΘΑΝΕΙΝ would have been widely known to Germans from Thucydides . The Greeks abandoned all of these for ΚΟΙΜΑΣΘΑΙ centuries ago.

Answer (score 4):

Heia oder heja kommt vom Heu. Man schlief auf Strohsäcken.  Das Ganze ist eine Mischung aus Babysprache und Dialekt.

Comment: Eine Quelle für die Aussage, dass es von "Heu" kommt wäre noch wünschenswert.

Comment: @userunknown Nach ein bisschen Recherche bin ich auf diese Seite gestoßen: http://www.heinrich-tischner.de/22-sp/9sp-ecke/artikel/200/2005/05-08-23.htm Weiterführende Quellen sind dort aber nicht verzeichnet.

Comment: See my comments on the Ancient Greek etymology. I rather believe this :)

Comment: @mthomas: Unfortunately the link seems broken.

Comment: WaybackMachine to the rescue: https://web.archive.org/web/20220129133700/https://www.heinrich-tischner.de/22-sp/9sp-ecke/artikel/200/2005/05-08-23.htm

Answer (score -2):

Der übliche Ausruf lautet *Ab in die Heia*, Falle, das Bett.

Bitte entschuldigen Sie, dass ich so durch den Wind bin. Ich kam ebend aus trockener Wärme in die Kälte und spüre da nun wieder im Warmen noch, wie sich mein Gesicht zusammen zieht. Darauf lese ich gegen den folgenden Anflug von Müdigkeit zufällig von einer relativ unsicheren urgermanischen Wurzel und sehene mich nach einem warmen Bett. Soviel zum vermutlichen Kontext.

***haj(ja)** neutrum "heat" (Kroonen 2013): nur älteres Niederländisch und in ähnlicher Bedeutung Althochdeutsch und Schweizer Deutsch sind belegt.

Siehe da [gehei](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/idmobil.htm#!page/10005/mode/1up) "Trockenheit" etc. im Idiotikon (G(e)hei I,​ Gei ,​ Kchei); weiter unten insbesondere auch "Gehege, nur in der RA. und in Flurnn.; in der ä. Spr. spec. gehegtes Holz" (G(e)hei II 2,851,​ Kchei (II)) und im Volltext:

> [...] Vgl. mhd. *hei(h)e*, Hegung, gehegter Wald, zum Vb. *hegen*, schützen, pflegen. [...] Hieher wohl auch die Fem.-Bildung *Stuet-Heie*, Flurn. (Wiessland) ThHw.

Vollständig erschließt sich mir das noch nicht.

Ich stelle darauf ab, die Heimkehr der Inbegriff, als man das Alltagsleben draußen zu verbringen hat (was den Kontext kaum eingrenzen lässt), hätte vielfältige Assoziationen geweckt. So vielfältig wie diese sein mögen, dürfte dem jedoch nur schwer beizukommen sein.

Unterdessen bezweifel ich, dass eine oberflächliche Analyse von *Heidschibumbeidschi* (sic!) im Bayerischen sachgemäß ist, wenn "heude, mu paidion" mehrere Lautwandel oder ähnliches eben nicht erklärt. Auch ist die Schreibung nicht sicher. Der angedeute Dental lässt vermutlich auf *Hitze* schließen.